# Power spectral density of a Poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes, fourier-analysis, poisson-process

Poisson processes can be used to model, for instance, shot noise, and are ubiquitous in many engineering, physical or biological problems.

What can be said about it's power spectral density? I haven't been able to find any references or derivations on the internet.

Comment: Poisson processes have no spectral component.  A spectral component implies that there is a correlation between $x(t)$ and $x(t+\tau)$ for some $\tau$, but a Poisson process never has any such correlation.

Comment: http://robotics.caltech.edu/~zoran/Research/poisson/node1.html

Comment: @Paul: there is correlation, namely $C(\tau) = r_0 \delta(\tau)$, so only at $\tau=0$.  Taking the Fourier transform of $C(\tau)$ yields the power spectrum, which is $\tilde{C}(f) = r_0$.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you are talking about a homogeneous or inhomogeneous Poisson process.

A homogeneous Poisson process is a form of white noise, and therefore like Gaussian white noise it has a flat power spectrum.  Its magnitude at all frequencies is equal to its rate, $\displaystyle r_0=\frac{1}{\langle\text{ISI}\rangle}$, where ISI=*interspike interval* and the angle brackets mean average over intervals.  The reason why it has a flat power spectrum even at arbitrarily large frequencies (meaning it has infinite variance) is due to the infinite magnitudes of the delta peaks in the time domain.

An inhomogeneous Poisson process is more complicated.  It will have more correlation than a homogeneous Poisson process, and therefore will not have a flat spectrum.  At some points in the spectrum , it may have reduced power (for instance at low frequencies due to increased regularity of firing) or increased power (at the average firing rate).  At higher frequencies it also approaches the firing rate as a homogeneous process does, again due to the delta peaks.

These systems are covered extensively in computational neuroscience texts:

Available online and probably easiest to follow:
https://neuronaldynamics.epfl.ch/online/Ch7.S5.html#SS3.p5

*Mathematics for Neuroscientists* by Gabbiani and Cox.

*Mathematical Foundations of Neuroscience*,  Ermentrout, G. Bard, Terman, David H.

*Handbook of Stochastic Methods* by C.W. Gardiner